# Elasticsearch indice take more size on disk than they appear

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I have several indices in elasticsearch, one of them has only around 100 documents in it, but it must be updated every other second.

Result of `GET _cat/indices` is as following:

```
green  open index1           8naYU5e-R-iHvfSKnrEiGw 1 0      2   9  25.5kb  25.5kb
yellow open index2           ZPQWzY7VRYGnBG0i6AL5ag 5 1   5658  89   1.2mb   1.2mb
yellow open index3           MTIDbt4uQbOv4K-0uuyOKA 5 1      0   0   1.1kb   1.1kb
yellow open index4           laF0UcIYTFKQQ6bB9dtQyw 5 1      0   0   1.1kb   1.1kb
yellow open index5           d5SYGXhYTPiVH_GKSA47lQ 5 1      0   0   1.1kb   1.1kb
yellow open index6           nIiNMwNWRZu-aISdLWa8ZA 5 1 110964  61  16.1mb  16.1mb
yellow open index7           g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA 5 1 111054 352  12.5mb  12.5mb
yellow open index8           C2g2RI_oQaOxUvpbzSnVIQ 5 1    123 400 484.8kb 484.8kb
```

As you can see, index7 has only 123 documents in it and it should not take more than 500kb on disk.

But result of `du -sh ./*` is like this:

```
128K    ./8naYU5e-R-iHvfSKnrEiGw
1.5G    ./C2g2RI_oQaOxUvpbzSnVIQ
172K    ./d5SYGXhYTPiVH_GKSA47lQ
1.1G    ./g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA
172K    ./laF0UcIYTFKQQ6bB9dtQyw
172K    ./MTIDbt4uQbOv4K-0uuyOKA
424M    ./nIiNMwNWRZu-aISdLWa8ZA
276M    ./ZPQWzY7VRYGnBG0i6AL5ag
```

It's taking more than 1GB on disk.

My question is why and how can I fix it?

I'm using elasticsearch 6.2.4 on Ubuntu 16.04

**UPDATE**

result of `du -sh ./g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/*`

```
3.2M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/0/index
8.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/0/_state
241M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/0/translog
3.1M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/1/index
8.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/1/_state
238M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/1/translog
3.2M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/2/index
8.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/2/_state
241M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/2/translog
3.1M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/3/index
8.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/3/_state
241M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/3/translog
3.1M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/4/index
8.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/4/_state
241M    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/4/translog
4.0K    ./indices/g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/_state/state-4.st
```

Comment: Do you have nested fields in your documents?

Comment: No, this document is has 1 dimension and has no nested documents in it

Comment: Can you add the result of `du -sh ./g492XL4ZRKy4NOIBwF1yzA/**/*` please?

Comment: I updated it with the result of the directory, thank you

Comment: Read carefully my comment, I asked for `.../**/*` not `/*`, thanks

Comment: Sorry, seems translog is taking most of the space

Comment: Yes, the translog is a file that contains all indexing operations, such that if a node goes down before the operations have been flushed to the Lucene index, operations can be replayed. You can learn more about translog here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html . Long story short, you should only consider the content of the `index` folders, which pretty much matches `store.size`

Comment: Thank you @Val, when will this operations be committed to the index? I fear that with the exponential growth of the translog size, I'll run out of disk space. Currently it's been running for about a day and its size is a concern.

Comment: As you can see in the link I provided, the maximum size of the translog file is 512mb by default, but you can modify that setting if you want. In your case, that means that the translog will take maximum 2.5GB of space on your harddisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size you measured using `du -h` on the index folder doesn't only include the size taken by the documents stored in the index, but also contains the [translog files](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-translog.html), which by default can go up to 512mb.

In your case, `_cat/indices` reveals that your `index7` index is 12.5mb big and when running `du -h` on your index folder, you can see that each `index` sub-folder located within each shard folder is approximately 3.1mb, so about the same magnitude as reported by `_cat/indices`.

Comment: Thank you sir.
I think I should set the settings for the translog files. Four translog files are now taking more than 512mb. Some are about a 1GB right now.

Comment: I reset the database and set the settings for translog retention size on 256mb to test the theory but i think it should fix the problem.

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it out!